# Find Product Names which contain character 'n'. Columns: ProductName;

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

```
create table Product(id integer, name varchar(100));    
insert into Product(id, name) values(1, 'Pen'); 
insert into Product(id, name) values(2, 'Paper');   
insert into Product(id, name) values(3, 'Printer'); 
insert into Product(id, name) values(4, 'Sharpner');    
insert into Product(id, name) values(5, 'Eraser');  
insert into Product(id, name) values(6, 'Clip');
```

The answer should  look like
name
Pen
Printer
Sharpner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want `like` in the `where` clause?

```
select name from product where name like '%n%';
```